# Writing characters/text in a ppm file

Tags: c, drawing, ppm

I'm currently in the last stretch of my university's C class and I am stumped on a small part of my homework. The homework takes a text file with lines of functions and converts them to a pixels in a ppm file to draw a picture. For example the text file will say

`SetColor 106 0 78
DrawLine 250 106 48 289`

where the color arguments are rgb values and the line arguments are the source and destination x y coordinates.
Now I have no problem with these. We just go ahead and change each pixel value and then write this to a ppm file. However the problem I have is with where we are supposed to also draw characters.

```
Boolean drawCharacter ( Image image , Point topLeft , char c , Color color )
```

is the function name and parameters in my c file. image is a struct that contains the height, width, and a pointer to the first pixel; Point contains col(x) and row(y) values, and color contains the rgb values.
The hint our teacher gave was that using bitwise operators would make our lives easier. Alas while I understand the concept of bitwise operators, this hint means nothing to me.

My question is does anybody have any idea on how I should approach this problem? How can I take a character and draw the text on a ppm file? The only solution I can think of is write out the solution for each char with a switch case or if statement. However I feel like there should also be a simpler solution. Sorry for the poor explanation, this problem has made me a bit sleep deprived.

Comment: Does the file format have much relevance? Surely you have an image buffer and build the image from the instructions, finally creating a file in the required format?

Comment: Im not sure which file you are talking about.
but yes we do have an image buffer, which I prefer to increase with the `ulimt -s unlimited` command

Comment: The one mentioned in the question title.

Comment: then yes it does. the reason a ppm file is required is because it is also easy to read as a text file. We write each pixels rgb value in order into the file and save it as a ppm. The ppm format just allows us to open and view the file as a picture

Comment: I presume the teacher's hint will be useful if the character image is a bitmap of one bit per pixel. You would then use a rotating mask to isolate each bit of each row of the character, to make a decision whether to set that pixel in the main image to `Color`'s colours.